# Formatting text from process to HTML

Tags: javascript, python, html, string

I am output from a process in python to be displayed on a webpage, however I am unable to format this text properly as `<br>`, `\n` and `\t` is rendered onto the page.

**Attempts**

- Replace `\n` with `<br>` or `<\br>`, then place changed text into `<p>` tag
- Use a `<pre>` tag with the unformatted text containing `\n` and `\t`
- encode the text as unicode on the server `line = unicode(output.strip())`
- removing all quotes from within string
- Tried using python html module but characters rendered as is `line = html.escape(output.strip())`

**Note**

I am using React so I cannot edit the DOM directly, I have to manipulate state.

**Example lines**

unformated i.e. leaving newlines etc

```
<pre className='console_text' key={i}>{el}</pre>
```

or (with replacements) i.e. replace newlines with br tag and tabs with spacing character

```
<p className='console_text' key={i}>{el}</p>
```

**Note also**

I am able to send other text from the server myself which contains newlines and it is formatted properly, I believe it has something to do with either the text formatting or some hidden character(s) that escapes everything but I am unable to find it, I'd appreciate any guidance.

**Console output**
[image: output from logging the text in the browser]

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape HTML characters, see [Escaping HTML](https://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml)

Comment: Please include all relevant parts of the linked resource in your response, as it may not be accessible to everyone (blocked, down, ...).

Comment: Just tried it, the characters renders as is, will update the question with this method as an attempt